# Python BeautifulSoup to csv scraping

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape some simple dictionary information from an html page. So far I am able to print all the words I need on the IDE. My next step was to transfer the words to an array. My last step was to save the array as a csv file... When I run my code it seems to stop taking information after the 1309th or 1311th word, although I believe there to be over 1 million on the web page. I am stuck and would be very appreciative of any help. Thank you

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen
import csv

html = urlopen('http://www.mso.anu.edu.au/~ralph/OPTED/v003/wb1913_a.html').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

words = []

for section in soup.findAll('b'):

    words.append(section.renderContents())

print ('success')
print (len(words))

myfile = open('A.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile)
wr.writerow(words)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce the problem (always getting 11616 items), but I suspect you have outdated `beautifulsoup4` or `lxml` versions installed. Upgrade:

```
pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
pip install --upgrade lxml
```

Of course, this is just a theory.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a good deal of your problem may lie in how you're processing the scraped content. Do you need to scrape all the content before you output it to the file? Or can you do it as you go?

Instead of appending over and over to a list, you should use `yield`.

```
def tokenize(soup_):
    for section in soup_.findAll('b'):
        yield section.renderContents()
```

This'll give you a generator that as long as section.renderContents() returns a string, the csv module can write out with no problem.